# How to fit a spline to data, keeping the fit at the ends of the data (Python)

Tags: scipy, interpolation, spline, data-fitting

I'm trying to smooth spline fit a bunch of data using scipy's functions and packages. For the most part, the spline fit works except at the beginning and end of the data where the fit goes off in a different direction. This is what I'm getting. [CurrentSpline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnTxk.png)

I want a fit that continues the trend of the data at the extreme end. I think the problem is that about 99% of the data is contained in the centred, as noted by the colour density. So I'm likely getting a good fit at the centre but not at the extreme ends.

I've been using splrep from scipy.interpolate. I've been playing around with knots, smoothing factors and degree but don't really get very close to what I want. The fits are all imperfect at the extreme ends. Is there a simple way to do this that isn't just trial and error?

```
spl = splrep(xdata, ydata, k=k,s=s, t=t)
xnew = np.linspace(-1,8)
ynew = splev(xnew, spl)
```

Comment: If you know the underlying function for your data, then you can use scipy's `curve_fit` functionality to find the parameters that give the best fit.

Comment: If you don't know the underlying function, you can try fitting a quadratic curve or an exponential one...

Comment: I don't the function but I'd like to use splines to keep the "fit" as generic as possible.

Comment: What is the data from? In the end, I think that `curve_fit` is the best option if you can define some generic function with unknown parameters that defines the data. For example, the data looks similar to the plot of 1/x, so you can add some constants to tune for a good fit.

Comment: The problem is, the data just doesn't match any generic function. I've tried 1/x and an exponential

Answer (score 0):

Scipy.interpolate allows to construct *interpolating* splines with given boundary conditions (via CubicSpline and make_interp_spline), but for smoothing splines this is currently missing: you can fit a natural smoothing spline (via make_smoothing_spline function), but that's currently it.

One other way is if you have an idea of the extrapolation behavior of the fit function, you can manually define a smooth functions with the desired asymptotics. YMMV though.